# Can we implement frontend and backend separately on AWS Elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I have frontend and backend both are using nodejs. Frontend is exposed and every request for api goes through the proxy module in the frontend, and both frontend and backend communicate on different modes.

Is there a way to deploy the above module, using code pipeline onto the Elastic Beanstalk platform ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not deploy the front end on Amplify AWS?

> AWS Amplify is a set of tools and services that can be used together or on their own, to help front-end web and mobile developers build scalable full stack applications, powered by AWS.

You just need to link your Repo and select your branch and everything will be deployed and generate also a random free domain or you can set your domain from the domain management section